# How to manually pass values to a Prediction Model in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

This is a newb question but I'm a newb.  So I can follow along ok with this example on building a predictive model:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/

My question is, now that I have this model built, how could I manually pass in these values to see what kind of Iris this is: [5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2].

I know I need to use the model.predict(), but I can't seem to get the data in the right format/fit.

I am just trying to learn by dissecting the example.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Make Predictions](https://machinelearningmastery.com/machine-learning-in-python-step-by-step/#crayon-59babee22ded8435135170) section, the author has the line

```
predictions = knn.predict(X_validation)
```

The argument that you pass to the predict method does not need to be a whole table.  You can also pass a single row to it.  Just make sure the orientation of the row you pass in is the same as the data you trained on.

If you're using a dataframe as input, for example, you probably did something like:

```
pd.DataFrame({"x1": [1,4,2,1,4,1], "x2": [7,9,7,7,6,8], ...})
```

So then, you could do

```
datapoint = pd.DataFrame({"x1": [1], "x2": [8], ...})
```

Pass the datapont object through all the prep you did to get your training data ready (eg scaler, onehot, etc), then pass it into the model's predict method:

```
datapoint_predict = knn.predict(datapoint)
```

Comment: knn.predict([[7.7,2.8,6.7,2.0]])  worked.  I think I had a syntax error the first time I tried it.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem!  glad to help